# Will installing PhoneGap 1.5 (Cordova) in XCode affect existing 1.0 apps?

Tags: cordova

I created several apps in iOS a while back using PhoneGap 1.0 and several plugins (ChildBrowser among others.) I'm about to start a new project and wanted to use the latest PhoneGap 1.5 (Cordova).

Will the installation of PhoneGap 1.5 into XCode effect my previous 1.0 apps should I need to make changes to them in the future?

I've googled around and checked the the PhoneGap wiki and cannot seem to find an answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I have couple of applications in development. One uses the older version and another uses the new one, as such both are running fine. I think the newer version will not affect your existing applications.

Comment: @dhaval Are the apps you're running in 1.0 / 1.5 as above? What version of XCode? Thanks!

Comment: one of my app is using 1.4 and the other is using 1.5. I am using xcode 4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using one application with 1.4 and another with 1.5. Although there is a considerable amount of change between these two versions the 1.5 might not overwrite previous version as it creates new template in XCode.

However you would like to go through the following reference to ensure your existing projects work as you expect.

http://blog.devgeeks.org/post/18313490602/how-to-keep-your-old-version-of-phonegap-for-ios-when#.T2FDIRH3NxM.twitter

Comment: You were correct that installing 1.5 created a separate template and left 1.0 alone; however with your link I was able to get 1.0, 1.4.1 (for plugins that don't work with 1.5) and 1.5 all in the same install. You sir are doing it like a boss! Thanks!